# How to release user touch on UISlider?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, uislider

I have such a problem... I want to block user's slider when he is sliding. I thought .isUserInteractionEnabled will handle that but it works only after the user releases slider.
I would like to 'steal' the slider from user and stop it.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a selector to your UISlider object. For instance, if you had a UISlider named "slider" you should do this:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
//runs a method called "sliderMoved" located in the same class as the slider (hence the addTarget:self) when the value is changed of the slider
```

and then you could make a method like this, which sets the value at the average whenever the user tries to slide the slider:

```
-(void)sliderMoved:(UISlider*)sender{
    sender.value = (sender.maximumValue + sender.minimumValue) / 2;
}
```

Comment: But I have already implemented "valueChanged". I won't to interrupt user when something another goes on. I thought maybe about some property? Don't know...

Comment: Have you implemented valueChanged on that specific slider? As long as you haven't attached another method to the ValueChanged property of that specific UISlider, you'll be fine. And if it is on the same UISlider, I must have misunderstood your question, because you said you did want to interrupt the user when they slide.